# google app script javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I am trying to use the wonderful Daff [library](https://github.com/paulfitz/daff) by Paul Fitz in a script designed to bring some version control to a google sheet Im working on. However I can't seem to include the javascript file in the script. I've tried importing it as an html file with  tags, and with an eval() call on an external source but both have produced either syntax errors or Undefined Exports errors. Any idea what this means? with a little research I see that this means node.js isn't included? Anyway around this or way to include library in the script? [Here](http://tristan-burke.com/daff.js) is external source.

Comment: Your second link is broken.  Also, please include your code in your question.

Comment: Have you tried using a full URL for the source? Using your link to the external source (which gives me a 404 error so you may need to edit this) `<script src="http://tristan-burke.com/daff.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The Answer Provide by Mr. Fritz himself involved deleting the first line of the file "#!/usr/bin/env node" and then wrapping the entire code in an init function to then call from outside!